# What does the "container" div class do on Weebly themes?

Tags: html, css, weebly

I'm quite a beginner to CSS and HTML as I'm trying to learn while making a webpage on Weebly

Anyways, I see a `container` div class after almost every div id. I was looking through the CSS and only saw a margin and width property for the div class by itself, but saw the `container` class as a child element after all id selectors. I was wondering what the `container` class actually does and why it is needed.

Example:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;   
}

#nav-wrap {
    background: url(nav-bg.jpg);
    box-shadow:0 1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}

#nav-wrap .container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

In the example above, which area does `#nav-wrap` indicate and which area does `#nav.wrap .container` indicate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`#nav-wrap` will correspond to an html tag id as nav-wrap.  `nav-wrap container` will be a compound styling; it will be an area where both the nav-wrap and container styles apply.  Read the source code.  If is your to tinker with, you might find drawing boxes with outline or changing div background colors instructive.

Answer (score 0):

At first in this code:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;   
}
```

the `margin: 0 auto` means the object with class `.container` aligned center horizontally and the rest is history ...

And after that the difference between `#nav-wrap` and `#nav-wrap .container`:

Suppose we have an html code like that:

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    ...
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

In this code and with the style you wrote, the `#nav-wrap .container` selector applies styles to inner `div` tag only but the `#nav-wrap` applies it's styles to whole of the code. In other words the inner `div` inherits `nav-wrap` styles but not vice versa.
I hope you understood ...